# How to remove leading zeros from string using C++?

Tags: c++, string

I want to remove leading zeroes from string like `"0000000057"`.

I did like this but didn't get any result:

```
string AccProcPeriNum = strCustData.substr(pos, 13);

string p48Z03 = AccProcPeriNum.substr(3, 10);
```

I want output only **57**.

Any idea in C++?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove leading zeroes?

Comment: You want to _remove_ _leading_ zeroes, by the way.

Comment: @cdhowie yes .....my value as its now 57 it may be after 3 digits or 4 digits i want o remove leading zeroes from that 10 charatcters string

Comment: Why? If you want the value, just convert it to integer, with say `aoti()`. If you want to keep it as a string, there's surely something wrong, as the leading zeros didn't get there by accident. Surely they are part of the defined format of a fixed size field?

Answer (score 39):

[Piotr S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25726706/2452869) is good but there is one case it will return the wrong answer, that is the all-zero case:

```
000000000000
```

To consider this in, use:

```
str.erase(0, std::min(str.find_first_not_of('0'), str.size()-1));
```

Even when `str.size()` will be `0`, it will also work.

Comment: If the question is "remove all leading zeros from a string", returning empty string for an all zeros string is not a wrong answer. Also, it is just by chance that this answers works also for empty strings, but `str.size()-1` is in general a pretty dangerous operation without guards.

Answer (score 38):

```
#include <string>    

std::string str = "0000000057";
str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of('0'));

assert(str == "57");
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/f8crcV)

Comment: if str = "0", it shouldn't do anything, but your code makes it an empty string

Comment: @sumanth232 This answer is correct given the question. A string `"0000000"` has all leading zeros so it should return an empty string, the question doesn't ask to return a string containing a valid number

Answer (score 3):

This should work as a generic function that can be applied to any of the `std::basic_string` types (including `std::string`):

```
template <typename T_STR, typename T_CHAR>
T_STR remove_leading(T_STR const & str, T_CHAR c)
{
    auto end = str.end();

    for (auto i = str.begin(); i != end; ++i) {
        if (*i != c) {
            return T_STR(i, end);
        }
    }

    // All characters were leading or the string is empty.
    return T_STR();
}
```

In your case you would use it like this:

```
string x = "0000000057";
string trimmed = remove_leading(x, '0');

// trimmed is now "57"
```

([See a demo](http://ideone.com/BAejcB).)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's probably *not* the most efficient (in terms of run-time speed) way to do things, I'd be tempted to just do something like:

```
std::cout << std::stoi(strCustData);
```

This is simple and straightforward to use, and gives a reasonable output (a single '0') when the input consists entirely of `0`s. Only when/if profiling showed that this simple solution was a problem would I consider writing substantially more complex code in the hopes of improving speed (and I doubt that would arise).

The obvious limitation here is that this does assume that the characters after the leading zeros are digits. That's clearly true in your sample, but I suppose it's conceivable that you have data where it's not true.

Comment: This also assumes that the resulting number is small enough to fit in an ```int```.

Comment: Why not use std::stoi64, it fit for both 32 (int) and 64 (unsigned int - not 64 but hit the limit of 32)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   string s="00000001";
   cout<<s<<endl;
   int a=stoi(s);
   cout<<a;
   //1 is ur ans zeros are removed


}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This C language friendly code removes leading zeros and can be used as long as the char array's length fits within an `int`:

```
char charArray[6] = "000342";
int inputLen = 6;

void stripLeadingZeros() {
    int firstNonZeroDigitAt=0, inputLen = strlen(charArray);

    //find location of first non-zero digit, if any
    while(charArray[firstNonZeroDigitAt] == '0')
        firstNonZeroDigitAt++;

    //string has no leading zeros
    if(firstNonZeroDigitAt==0)
        return; 

    // string is all zeros
    if(firstNonZeroDigitAt==inputLen) {
        memset(charArray, 0, sizeof charArray);
        strcpy(charArray, "0");
        inputLen = 1;
        return;
    }

    //shift the non-zero characters down
    for(int j=0; j<inputLen-firstNonZeroDigitAt; j++) {
        charArray[j] = charArray[firstNonZeroDigitAt+j];
    }

    //clear the occupied area and update string length
    memset(charArray+inputLen-firstNonZeroDigitAt, 0, inputLen-firstNonZeroDigitAt+1);
    inputLen -= firstNonZeroDigitAt;
}
```