# Why is my if statement not evaluating false when it should be?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement

In this part of my program, I want to take out the leading 0s in the string highScore. Here is what I have (not the entire program; this is just the part I'm having issues with):

```
//take out leading 0s
for (int i = 0; highScore.at(i) != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (highScore.at(i) == '0')
        highScore = highScore.erase(0, 1);
    else
      break;
}
```

The highScore string contains the string "000500000" in it, so after the variable i becomes 3, it should leave the loop (at least, that's what I want it to do) but instead it continues to loop through the string 2 more times and then outputs this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 4)
```

I am a little confused about this since I don't think I'm doing anything that would throw the string out of range.

Comment: What is `highScore`? Hint: Will `std::string` ever contain a NUL byte unless you explicitly put one there? What you probably mean is `i < highScore.length()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove leading zeros from string using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726531/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-string-using-c)

Comment: C strings are null-terminated, but C++ `std::string`s are not.

Comment: Adding to what @NateEldredge said, if you really want to go this way you can get c_str().

Comment: `highScore = highScore.erase(0, 1);` 1) The assignment is redundant, just `erase` will suffice. 2) You check the `i`'th index, but always erase at index `0`. 3) Step through the loop and pay attention to `highScore` and `i` during the first couple of iterations.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize that C++ strings weren't null-terminated as well. And thank you @dxiv I realize that now!

Comment: C++ `std::string` is a whole different deal than C strings. They *can* contain NUL bytes if you want, but they're not treated as a delimiter. Unlike C, there's an internal length tracking property that stores how much data each string contains so you can store whatever you want.

Comment: "std::string is not null-terminated" needs some clarification. The buffer used inside `std::string` *is* null-terminated, and you can access it using `.data()` or `.c_str()` members. But you are not allowed to access that '\0' by iterating the string object, and it is not included in `.size()`.

Comment: "*I want to take out the leading 0s*" - there is a *much* easier way to implement that, using [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of): `highScore.erase(0, highScore.find_first_not_of('0'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're both shortening the string and advancing the subscript.  That takes you out of bounds pretty quickly.  Your `if` should always test `.at(0)`, and your loop, as others noted above, should test the size().  You can't look for the end with `'\0'`.

Comment: Wow, completely looked over that fact.Thank you, this solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is every time you call `highScore.erase()`, the length of `String highScore` gets changed.
I prefer you to count the number of zeroes first, and then apply `.erase()` at the end.
Have a look

```
int zeroCount = 0;
for(int i=0; i<highScore.length(); i++){
     if(highScore.at(i) == '0'){
          zeroCount++;
     }
     else{
          break;
     }
}
highScore.erase(0,c);
```

Comment: Possibly: `auto zeroCount = std::distance(highScore.begin(), std::find_if(highScore.begin(), highScore.end(), [](char c){ return c != '0'; });`