# Trimming 0 from a string

Tags: c++, string, substring

Suppose I have string like "0003443" and our goal is to achive "3443". I have done this using substring method finding out number of zero's but I want to know the most optimal way of doing this in c++.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726531/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-string-using-c

Comment: ut I wanted to know the most optimal way to do it

Comment: You will find that "most optimal" is not well defined.  Do you mean fastest?  If so how does the data look like?  Do you run this once?  1e6 times?  How many zeros are there on average?  How many strings have no leading zeros?  What's the capability of your host?  Do you want to use AVX instructions and if so what kind?  Another optional might be shortest code.

Comment: "Most optimal" might be to not generate strings with unwanted leading zeroes in the first place.  Then no leading-zero-removal is necessary, and in that scenario your leading-zero-removal step is a no-op and therefore optimally efficient.

Comment: Finding the number of zeros and then using `substr` sounds optimal to me. Can you think of any process that would be more optimal? Of course it does all depend upon what you mean by 'optimal'. I get the feeling that when beginners ask what is most optimal or efficient or best without defining any of those terms it's simply because they lack confidence in their own code. It's like they think there some secret trick that experts know but they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test/run this code in https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/TrimLeftZeros#main.cpp

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <chrono>


time_t CurrentEpochMilliseconds()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

std::string TrimZeros1(const std::string& number)
{
    std::regex regex(u8"[-+]?[0-9]{1,}", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript); 
    if(!std::regex_match(number, regex)) //Validating number format +XXXXX or -XXXXX or XXXXX
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid parameter, it is not a number.");
    }

    std::string result = number;
    size_t pos = 0;
    if(result[0] == '+') 
    {
        result.erase(0,1);
    }
    if(result[0] == '-')
    {
        pos = 1;
    }

    while (result.size()>0 && result[pos]== '0') 
    {
        result.erase(pos,1); //Erase first char. Pos = pos, Count = 1
    }
    return (pos == 1 && result.size() ==1) || result.size() == 0 ? u8"0" : result; 
}

std::string TrimZeros2(const std::string& number)
{
    std::regex regex(u8"[-+]?[0-9]{1,}", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    if(!std::regex_match(number, regex))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid parameter, it is not a number.");
    }

    int result = std::stoi(number);
    return std::to_string(result);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<u8"--- TrimZeros1"<< std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"0000000") << std::endl;

    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"+0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"+0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"+0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"+0000000") << std::endl;

    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"-0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"-0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"-0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros1(u8"-0000000") << std::endl;

    std::cout <<std::endl;

    std::cout<<u8"--- TrimZeros2"<< std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"0000000") << std::endl;

    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"+0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"+0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"+0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"+0000000") << std::endl;

    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"-0003443") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"-0000123") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"-0000789") << std::endl;
    std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"-0000000") << std::endl;

    //std::cout<< TrimZeros2(u8"") << std::endl; //Error it is not a valid number value.

    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;

    int iterations = 10000;
    std::cout<<u8"--- Started - TrimZeros1 - Time Test"<< std::endl;
    time_t actual = CurrentEpochMilliseconds();
    for(int i = 0; i< iterations; i++)
    {
        TrimZeros1(u8"+0000000");
        TrimZeros1(u8"-0000000");
        TrimZeros1(u8"0000000");
        TrimZeros1(u8"+1111112");
        TrimZeros1(u8"-1111112");
        TrimZeros1(u8"1111112");
    }
    actual = CurrentEpochMilliseconds() - actual;
    std::cout << ("Elapsed seconds = " + std::to_string(actual / 1000.0) + "  ---  Elapsed milliseconds = " + std::to_string(actual) + "  ---  Elapsed minutes = " + std::to_string((actual / 1000.0) / 60.0)) << std::endl;
std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;

    
    std::cout<<u8"--- Started - TrimZeros2 - Time Test"<< std::endl;
    actual = CurrentEpochMilliseconds();
    for(int i = 0; i< iterations; i++)
    {
        TrimZeros2(u8"+0000000");
        TrimZeros2(u8"-0000000");
        TrimZeros2(u8"0000000");
        TrimZeros2(u8"+1111112");
        TrimZeros2(u8"-1111112");
        TrimZeros2(u8"1111112");
    }
    actual = CurrentEpochMilliseconds() - actual;
    std::cout << ("Elapsed seconds = " + std::to_string(actual / 1000.0) + "  ---  Elapsed milliseconds = " + std::to_string(actual) + "  ---  Elapsed minutes = " + std::to_string((actual / 1000.0) / 60.0)) << std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;

    std::cout<< u8"Press enter to continue... ";
    std::cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
--- TrimZeros1
3443
123
789
0
3443
123
789
0
-3443
-123
-789
0

--- TrimZeros2
3443
123
789
0
3443
123
789
0
-3443
-123
-789
0


--- Started - TrimZeros1 - Time Test
Elapsed seconds = 106.251000  ---  Elapsed milliseconds = 106251  ---  Elapsed minutes = 1.770850


--- Started - TrimZeros2 - Time Test
Elapsed seconds = 99.248000  ---  Elapsed milliseconds = 99248  ---  Elapsed minutes = 1.654133


Press enter to continue...
```

**clang++ - web/online https://repl.it**

[image: clang++ web/online]

**g++ local machine**

[image: g++ local machine]

**clang++ local machine**

[image: clang++ local]

Comment: It would be nice if you even show time comparison.  BTW thanks

Comment: Your second trim function requires a condition that the string is in range of long which may not be true

Comment: Added time comparison, number validation.